# ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

After adding the following Relative Layout and nested elements (ImageView, TextView) to the main layout, my app force closes when opening, with the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`:

**Here's the stacktrace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.fogtechnologies.expotec.urban, PID: 2898
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fogtechnologies.expotec.urban/com.fogtechnologies.expotecshell.urban.activities.ActivityExpotecMainView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.mai(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
     at com.fogtechnologies.expotecshell.urban.activities.ActivityExpotecMainView.findViews(ActivityExpotecMainView.java:163)
     at com.fogtechnologies.expotecshell.urban.activities.ActivityExpotecMainView.onCreate(ActivityExpotecMainView.java:77)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Here is the snippet from my layout file:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="downloadEventButtonAction"
        android:src="@drawable/now_performing_shape"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:scaleX="0.9"
        android:scaleY="0.9"
        android:text="Download Event" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```

Here's the code line with the issue:

`tvMainDownloadEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainDownloadEvent);`

Changing the `(TextView)` to `(ImageView)` doesn't fix this.

How do I change the ID's type to ImageView?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Pretty clear exception, you're trying to cast an ImageView to a TextView at line 163 in your class ActivityExpotecMainView.java.

Comment: Show your java code

Comment: Didyou search/read  ClassCastException before posting question?

Comment: You're exactly right. The exception points me to where the problem is in my code. I had assumed the problem was only in my layout file.

Comment: I just edited my question to clarify what my question is and to include the code line wherein lies the issue. Hopefully some downvotes will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use`tvMainDownloadEvent` for textview and `ivMainDownloadEvent` for imageview.

Change layout to

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="downloadEventButtonAction"
        android:src="@drawable/now_performing_shape"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ivMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/ivMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivMainDownloadEvent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:scaleX="0.9"
        android:scaleY="0.9"
        android:text="Download Event" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, and thanks also if you didn't downvote my question.

Answer (score 4):

Your Logcat throws **[ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

Problem starts from

```
 android:id="@+id/tvMainDownloadEvent"
```

is your **TextView** Id .Do not set this in **ImageView** Section .

You should change this from your Java Class .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your java code, not in xml. Most likely you confuced the `TextView` and `ImageView` id's in `findViewById()` method.